# Entity Framework 6 executing query on navigation property access when related entities already loaded

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working around lazy loading issues (yes, I'll be investigating turning it off as well). For simplification, imagine I have three tables, TableA, TableB and TableC, in one-to-many relationships: TableA 1->* TableB 1->* TableC.

For various reasons, I am avoiding Including TableC in the initial query, so my first step looks like:

```
var data = ctx.TableA.Include("TableB").Where(it => it.ID = 5);
```

Since I have all the entities I need in TableB, I'm gathering their primary keys and using that to do a bulk load of related entities in TableC.

```
var ids = data.SelectMany(it => it.TableB.ID).ToList();
```

I have tried the following two ways:

```
var x1 = ctx.TableC.Where(it => ids.Contains(it.TableB_ID)).ToList();
var x2 = ctx.TableC.SqlQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM TableC WHERE TableB_ID in ({0})", String.Join(",", ids.Select(it => it.ToString())))).ToList();
```

Through debugging, I can see all the queries getting executed.

**My question is: When I execute the following code, EF executes a query to load the related TableC entities when my expectation would be that no SQL query would be executed because the requested entities are already loaded.**

```
foreach (var tb in data.TableB)
{
    var res = tb.TableC;
    DoSomething(res);
}
```

I understand that there are things here that may be bad practice, I'd really just like to understand what's happening with regard to this particular setup rather than get into a deep discussion of coding practice, unless it bears directly on the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing here

```
var x1 = ctx.TableC.Where(it => ids.Contains(it.TableB_ID)).ToList();
```

(which preferably should be

```
ctx.TableC.Where(it => ids.Contains(it.TableB_ID)).Load();
```

which is the same, but without list creation overhead)

is a variation of the [Explicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2) and more generally, a so called *navigation property fix-up*.

However, although it populates the corresponding collections, they are not marked as loaded, so the lazy loading will still try to load them on the first access of the property. It's because this technique does not guarantee that the collection is fully loaded and is used for instance to load filtered data, as explained in the **Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities** section of the linked documentation topic. After the provided example, you could notice the following:

> When using the Query method it is usually best to turn off lazy loading for the navigation property. This is because otherwise the entire collection may get loaded automatically by the lazy loading mechanism either before or after the filtered query has been executed.

which applies to your case as well.

Shortly, when planning to use such explicit loading techniques, you'd better turn lazy loading off, otherwise it will effectively make all that effort redundant and in fact will have negative impact of the whole process.